# K piles stone game

Tags: algorithms, game-theory

Their are k piles with total n stones in some order where each pile can have stones greater or equal to zero.Two player A and B plays a game in which player A cant see the configuration of piles but he knows the size of each pile only order is unknown to him.Player A points to a pile and Player B removes one stone from that pile.

If their is no stone in that pile player B informs player A that this pile is empty.

Now the Player A wants atleast C stones in minimum moves.I want to find the minimum moves P so that Player A gets atleast C stones after P moves whatever be the initial configuration of piles.

Like if we have three piles and six stones and player A needs to get four of them . Then minimum moves required to get 4 stones is 4.

Comment: If the initial configuration is $4,1,1$, A may need $6$ moves in order to get $4$ stones: there is no strategy that guarantees that he won’t point twice at an empty pile.

Comment: I want to tell minimal value P for which there exists an initial stones distribution and moves strategy that makes Player A win no matter what order the Piles are in.

Comment: I can get it in above example in 4 moves if all the 3 piles have 2,2,2 stones .Then Player A point to one pile two times and any other pile two times to get total of 4 stones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** My original answer was based on a misunderstanding of the problem and was actually wrong even for that interpretation. The problem as it now stands seems somewhat difficult. This is not an answer, and I may end up deleting it, but it does include some ideas that may be useful and shows why a complete answer may be a bit complicated, so I’ll leave it up for now.

Suppose that the piles have $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k$ stones, where $a_1\le a_2\le\ldots\le a_m=\ldots=a_k$. If $C\le a_1$, then of course Player $A$ will need only $C$ moves. It’s also clear that if $m=1$, so that all piles are the same size, Player $A$ will need only $C$ moves. Suppose that $m>1$ and $C>a_1$. In the worst case Player $A$ picks the smallest pile $a_1+1$ times and collects $a_1$ stones. If $m=2$ or $C\le a_1+a_2$, he need not make any more bad moves, so he can collect $C$ stones in $C+1$ moves. If $m>2$ and $C>a_1+a_2$, he could make $2$ bad moves in collecting the first $a_1+a_2$ stones. If $m=3$ or $C\le a_1+a_2+a_3$, he need not make any more bad moves, so he can collect $C$ stones in $C+2$ moves.

Let $b_0=0$, and for $i=1,\ldots,k$ let $b_i=a_0+\ldots+a_i$. Suppose that $b_i<C\le b_{i+1}$; if $m>i$, Player $A$ could make $i$ bad moves in collecting the first $b_i$ stones and therefore need altogether $C+i$ moves to collect $C$ stones. However, he never needs more than $m-1$ bad moves to reach a position in which all piles are the same size, so he actually needs at most $$C+\min\{m-1,i\}$$ moves to collect $C$ stones. For fixed $n,k$, and $C$, therefore, we want to choose $a_1,\ldots,a_k$ so as to minimize $\min\{m-1,i\}$, where $i$ is the unique index such that $b_i<C\le b_{i+1}$.

Comment: What is q in your above explanation.?

Comment: @user3001932: It’s defined implicitly in the first sentence: it’s a basic fact that there are a unique $q$ and $r$ satisfying those conditions. It can be explicitly defined as $\left\lfloor\frac{n}k\right\rfloor$.

Comment: Now,Can i say r then to be n%k ? Then can u solve above example by yur explanation ?

Comment: @user3001932: If you’re using C syntax and mean what I’d write $r=n\bmod k$, then yes, that’s what $r$ turns out to be. In your example $r=0$, $q=2$ and $kq=6=n$, so for any $C\le 6$ you need just $C$ moves.

Comment: Nice explanation.Thanx

Comment: @user3001932: You’re welcome!

Comment: I am getting it wrong for N=4 K=3 AND C=4.It should be 5 but getting 6

Comment: @user3001932: It is $6$, not $5$. The piles are $2,1,1$, and the first $3$ moves take $1$ from each. $A$ can now be really unlucky and make $2$ bad moves, finally getting the last stone on the sixth move.

Comment: No suppose the intital configuraion is 2 2 0 then in worst case he will first choose third pile with 0 stones .Then he will choose one of the remaining two piles two times consecutively and as he knew that it has two stones only after taking both from that pile he select last pile two times consecutively.so total of 5 moves.I think i forgot to mention that A knew that their is a pile of 0 stone , 1 stone ,2 stone..But does not knew in which pile their is 0 stone,1 stone or 2 stone etc

Comment: @user3001932: I was assuming that $k$ was the number of **non-empty** piles.

Comment: @user3001932: However, my solution still isn’t necessarily optimal: from $3,3,1$ player $A$ can guarantee to get $7$ stones in $8$ moves even without knowing the sizes of the piles, while from my suggestion of $3,2,2$ it could take $9$ moves. I’ll have to think about it some more.

Comment: hmm..n it can be empty.No such constraint on it

Comment: @user3001932: You should add two things to the question. (1) A pile can be empty initially. (2) Player $A$ knows the sizes of the piles; it’s just their order that is unknown. Both of these affect the result.

Comment: I edited it..And sorry for inconvinence

Comment: @user3001932: That’s okay; I’m just glad to get it straightened out.

Comment: ok..You get the solution now?

Comment: @user3001932: I’m afraid not; it’s a harder problem than I originally thought, and I’m going to have to spend some time on it. I doubt that I’ll have an answer right away.

Comment: Ok..take your time..I am also trying it

Comment: sorry, but what exactly is $m$? can we define $m$?I don't understand what it is.

Comment: @user69608: $m$ is defined in the first sentence of the second paragraph. If we list the $k$ piles in non-decreasing order of their sizes, the $m$-th pile is the first one that is the same size as the last pile. Equivalently, $m$ is the integer such that there are $m-1$ piles that are strictly smaller than the largest pile.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott if $m=1$ and $C>a_1$,how will it need only $C$ moves?it can choose $a_1$ times first element and when $a_1$ has become zero,it again chooses $a_1$ which results in bad move and making moves greater than $C$?

Comment: @user69608: You’re forgetting that Player $A$ knows the sizes of the piles. In your example $A$ knows that every pile has $a_1$ stones, so after pointing to the first pile $a_1$ times, $A$ will point to the second pile. Thus, no bad moves are required.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott wow, i completely didn't think about that. I got it now and thanks for replying eventhough the problem was too old.really appreciated.

Comment: @user69608: You’re very welcome.